# Error trying to fetch from public REST API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to perform a fetch to a remote API within a React application.  Unfortunately, while testing, I keep getting the following error:

> Security Error: Content at http://localhost:3000/? may not load data from [http://geocode.maps.co/search?q={64102}](http://geocode.maps.co/search?q=%7B64102%7D)

Here's the relevant code:

```
export default function SearchBar() {
    const [ input, setInput ] = useState('');
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const fetchMyCoords = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://geocode.maps.co/search?q={${input}}`);
            const jsonData = await response.json();

            const { lat, lon } = jsonData['0'] ?? { lat: 39.76, lon: -98.50 };
            dispatch(setMyCoords([ lat, lon ]));
        } catch(err) {
            console.error('fetchMyCoords: fetch failed:', err);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId='searchBar'>
                <Form.Control
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='Enter post code'
                    onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}
                    value={input}
                />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button onClick={fetchMyCoords}>Search</Button>
        </Form>
    );
}
```

The fetch function is supposed to be called when input is entered and the "search" button is pushed, and as far as I can tell this is working fine -- the fetch just immediately fails.  From reading through others with similar issues I know one possibility is some kind of CORS problem, but I'm not sure how that could be resolved -- I have no access to the API server, it's a public service.  I do know I can access the API just fine via my browser (Firefox), so it doesn't seem like it's an IP-level problem.  Anyone have any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** I tried switching to a different API provider (positionstack) and the problem persists with the same error message.  I'm testing the application via the built-in React development server (i.e. the one `npm start` initiates).

Comment: Did you try using http**s**?

Comment: Adding https seems to work, it does have cors headers, so it should work.

Comment: Yeah, I had it set to HTTPS first before falling back to HTTP.  The results were the same.

@dandavis did you test this?  If so, how?  I'm using the React development server and accessing the page via localhost.